# Open Street Map “no map for: default”

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, linux

I'm hitting my head off a wall!
I Have installed **renderd** and **mapnik** on Debain squeeze v6.0.5. Renderd`(version 0.7.1)` is starting without error. But when I request the `/osm_tiles2/0/0/0.png` . The server times out would not found and the console  **no map for: default**

and google is no help :(

Huge Thanks

Comment: Question is not clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at www.switch2osm.org and use the offered packages that run out-of-the-box.